# Is there a way to see a log everytime an app crash?

Tags: applications

My android phone sometimes quit applications unexpectedly. There is no trace.

I don't see anything wrong. It just quits.

I made a video out of it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzAuaIw4RT0

I wonder if there is anyway I can

1. Check some log when it happens (without rooting because it'll void warranty)
2. Scan the hard disk of cell phone for errors
3. Scan memory

Comment: I can't check the video for some reason, so which Android version and device are you using? You can check crash logs using [tag:logcat]. See [tag:logging] for more info.  If you're getting ANR messages, you would get related logs under /data/anr (see [how to access android files /data/anr/traces.txt and /data/tombstones/tombstones](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5467972))

Comment: what is anr? I'll see logcat

Comment: Can anyone else check the video? are there any asus forum?